# Unexpected code bundle "Alcatraz.xcplugin"

Tags: xcode

I came to know about Alcatraz from Apress book "Troubleshooting Xcode". I'm getting the following warning upon xcode launch after installing Alcatraz.

> The “Alcatraz.xcplugin” code bundle is not provided by Apple. Loading
>   code not provided by Apple can have a negative effect on the safety
>   and stability of Xcode or related tools.

[image]

I've searched for Alcatraz here and many developers seem using it. Just wanted to know whether it's worth using with this warning message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just warning from Apple. No problem with it. If you using Alcatraz you can install alot of plugin very userfull. You can reference to:

[Xcode Plugins](http://iosdevtips.co/post/82232620790/best-xcode-plugins)

[Xcode Plusgins NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/xcode-plugins/)

You can try it.

Comment: considering that there won't be any security issues, I'm accepting your answer. 1+

Comment: Can we suppress this warning?

Comment: @PratikSomaiya I think it is no.

Comment: @vienvu: Ok. No problem. Thanks for quick revert. :)